# Simulating hadoop fs command (hadoop fs -cat) with the Hadoop FileSystem API

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hdfs

We have a service running over JBoss which retrieves files from a remote.
Due to past circumstances, we weren't able to use the Hadoop FS API, so we used System calls with the actual command (we used: hadoop fs -cat ).

Now, We're moving those system calls to their equivalent API Hadoop FS API.

My need is to get the file from HDFS as InputStream (or FSDataInputStream) and pass it to a http response.
We would like to avoid saving the file locally and then writing it into a stream.

Basically this works, but I face 2 problems.

1. I don't know when I can call FileSystem.close() as I don't know if the streaming is finished.
2. I get an EOFException once the stream is over:

   ```
   19:09:41,446 INFO  [STDOUT] [DEBUG] [http-127.0.0.1-8888-1] Error making BlockReader. Closing stale NioInetPeer(Socket[addr=/192.168.20.198,port=50010,localport=56503]) [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient]
   java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsProtoUtil.vintPrefixed(HdfsProtoUtil.java:171)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:392)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.newBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:137)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1084)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:538)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:750)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:794)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
   at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:114)
   at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:76)
   at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:98)
   at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:59)
   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at com.liveperson.dataaccess.management.filters.DevFilter.doFilter(DevFilter.java:60)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at com.liveperson.dataaccess.management.filters.ValidationFilter.doFilter(ValidationFilter.java:74)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at com.liveperson.gatekeeper.oauth.filter.GateKeeperFilter.doFilter(GateKeeperFilter.java:117)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at com.liveperson.dataaccess.management.filters.CountersFilter.doFilter(CountersFilter.java:32)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   ```

Thanks in advance for any help!